# Eclipse/Maven: QueryDSL and SQL Server Issue Using Integrated Security

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, jdbc, querydsl, m2e

Relevant details for the IDE:

- Eclipse 2018-09
- m2e 1.9.1.20180912-1601

A few high level details:

- I'm using Maven and QueryDSL to generate Data Transfer Objects and Query classes for two databases in SQL Server
- The JDBC connection in Maven needs to use integrated security (i.e. no stored passwords/SQL Server database authentication). This requires use of the sqljdbc_auth.dll native library.
- This setup largely works, but only for the first Maven -> 'Update Project' after starting Eclipse. Even on the first run of the project update, it appears that something in Maven runs more than once and causes an exception. If I make any schema changes, then I have to Restart Eclipse to successfully update the Maven project. On the first run and subsequent runs I have at least two persistent Maven errors, though they change from first to subsequent runs.
- Changing IDEs (ex. Eclipse -> IntelliJ) has a high cost right now and not a good option.
- I'm open to using something other than QueryDSL if there is an ORM that works better (note I primarily work in .Net, but have occasional Java projects such as this one).
- In summary I have two questions - identified as Question 1 and Question 2 below in bold.

Below is a redacted pom.xml, but includes enough information to reproduce (or identify that it can't be reproduced):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
    <artifactId>REDACTED</artifactId>
    <version>REDACTED</version>
    <name>REDACTED</name>
    <description>REDACTED</description>
    <properties>
        <querydsl.version>4.2.1</querydsl.version>
        <mssql.version>7.0.0.jre8</mssql.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.10</source>
                    <target>1.10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>database1</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbcDriver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</jdbcDriver>
                            <jdbcUrl>jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=database1;integratedSecurity=true;</jdbcUrl>
                            <packageName>REDACTED.database1</packageName>
                            <exportBeans>true</exportBeans>
                            <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>database2</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbcDriver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</jdbcDriver>
                            <jdbcUrl>jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=database2;integratedSecurity=true;</jdbcUrl>
                            <packageName>REDACTED.database2</packageName>
                            <exportBeans>true</exportBeans>
                            <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- <execution> <goals> <goal>export</goal> </goals> </execution> -->
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${mssql.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
                <artifactId>optaplanner-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${mssql.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Eclipse produces two types of errors, an error involving multiple writes to a file and an error involving the native authentication library:

```
Execution database1 of goal com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export failed: Attempted to write multiple times to <PATH>\CheckConstraints.java, please check your configuration (com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export:database1:validate)
... 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to write multiple times to <PATH>\CheckConstraints.java, please check your configuration
```

**Question 1: Is there something off with the pom.xml file or an eclipse setting somewhere that would cause Maven to run the querydsl plugin executions more than once per validate phase of the maven build? Should I use a different phase than validate? Something else entirely?**

Updating the maven project in eclipse more than once causes the following errors:

```
This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:12c300a7-0674-41a1-8e64-16040e9dbde3 (com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export:database2:validate)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:12c300a7-0674-41a1-8e64-16040e9dbde3
...
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:12c300a7-0674-41a1-8e64-16040e9dbde3
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Windows\System32\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

This error is repeated for database2 as well. The ... are long sections of stack trace that might or might not be helpful. I've posted the full stack trace for both error types at the bottom of the question.

Research into this error indicates that there is likely a classloader/lifetime related issue to Maven and Eclipse. I'm not sure if Maven and Eclipse share a classloader, but the conclusion of the Maven -> 'Update Project' method is not causing the native library, sqljdbc_auth.dll, to be unloaded and subsequent updates are causing the Microsoft JDBC driver to attempt to reload the native library.

**Question 2: How do I make Maven run in Eclipse in such a way as to have the native library, sqljdbc_auth.dll, unloaded (or the previously loaded native library reused)?**

Below are the full stack traces for the two types of errors:

Error Type 1:

```
Execution database1 of goal com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export failed: Attempted to write multiple times to <PATH>\CheckConstraints.java, please check your configuration (com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export:database1:validate)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution database1 of goal com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export failed: Attempted to write multiple times to <Path>\CheckConstraints.java, please check your configuration
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to write multiple times to <PATH>\CheckConstraints.java, please check your configuration
    at com.querydsl.sql.codegen.MetaDataExporter.write(MetaDataExporter.java:431)
    at com.querydsl.sql.codegen.MetaDataExporter.serialize(MetaDataExporter.java:413)
    at com.querydsl.sql.codegen.MetaDataExporter.handleTable(MetaDataExporter.java:393)
    at com.querydsl.sql.codegen.MetaDataExporter.handleTables(MetaDataExporter.java:260)
    at com.querydsl.sql.codegen.MetaDataExporter.export(MetaDataExporter.java:251)
    at com.querydsl.maven.AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.execute(AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.java:538)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 31 more
```

Error Type 2:

```
This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:12c300a7-0674-41a1-8e64-16040e9dbde3 (com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export:database2:validate)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:12c300a7-0674-41a1-8e64-16040e9dbde3
    at com.querydsl.maven.AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.execute(AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.java:547)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:12c300a7-0674-41a1-8e64-16040e9dbde3
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2826)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:73)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3550)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3541)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2395)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.querydsl.maven.AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.execute(AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.java:536)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Windows\System32\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:52)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3549)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3541)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2395)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.querydsl.maven.AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.execute(AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.java:536)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    ... 1 more
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please ask one and only one question per question, these are two entirely different subjects.

Comment: Perhaps I missed it in your comment, but you were able to provide assistance with which question? The questions are distinctly connected in this case, differing only by whether it involves the first run or subsequent Maven runs within Eclipse. Someone with specific expertise in this area might see a connection where you don't.

Comment: if you have multiple schemas in the database with same table names you need to filter the schemas you want to export by using  <schemaPattern>schemaName</schemaPattern> inside the querydsl-maven-plugin configuration.